# How to place the cursor in a custom postion when completion happens?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to create a completion for JavaScript. I have the following exampe for the completion.

```js
var jsonob = {
    label: String(counter.label),
    kind: counter.kind, 
    insertText: counter.insertText,     
};
completionList.push(jsonob);
```

and counter.insertText has the `"function ${1:functionName} (){\n\t\n}"` String

when the completion happens what it shows is

```js
function ${1:functionName} (){

}
```

but it should highlight the word functionName. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that your `counter.insertText` is a plain `string`. [`CompletionItem.insertText`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem.insertText) is defined as follows:

> ```
> insertText?: string | SnippetString
> ```
>
> A string or snippet that should be inserted in a document when selecting this completion. When `falsy` the label is used.

So if you want your `insertText` to be treated as a snippet, you'll have to wrap it in a [`SnippetString`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SnippetString) instance.

```js
insertText: new vscode.SnippetString("function ${1:functionName} (){\n\t\n}")
```

---

If you're using the Language Server Protocol rather than the VSCode API, there is no `SnippetString`. Simply use a snippet string directly in `insertText` and then set `CompletionItem.insertTextFormat` to `InsertTextFormat.Snippet`:

```js
insertText: "function ${1:functionName} (){\n\t\n}",
insertTextFormat: InsertTextFormat.Snippet
```

Note: `insertTextFormat` applies to both `insertText` and `textEdit`.